# SQL joining 6 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

Please take a look at the image.There are 5tables related to appointTable with appointID.
Now i need all the data with same appointment id..what should be the joining query?Can any one help me about it?[image]

Here is the generated query(I am using Left outer Join)

```
SELECT     dbo.Appointment.appointment_id, dbo.Appointment.patient_id, dbo.PatientInvestigaiton.investigation_name, dbo.PatientInvestigaiton.investigation_id, 
           dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.medecine_id, dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.medicinename, dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.medicinetype, 
           dbo.PatientFindings.finding_id, dbo.PatientFindings.finding_value, dbo.PatientAdvice.advice_description, dbo.PatientCC.cc_value, dbo.PatientCC.cc_id, 
           dbo.PatientDiagonosis.diagonosis_name, dbo.PatientDiagonosis.diagonosis_id

FROM       dbo.Appointment LEFT OUTER JOIN

           dbo.PatientInvestigaiton ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientInvestigaiton.appointment_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.appointment_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.PatientFindings ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientFindings.appointment_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.PatientDiagonosis ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientDiagonosis.appointment_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.PatientCC ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientCC.appointment_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.PatientAdvice ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientAdvice.appointment_id

           where dbo.Appointment.appointment_id='46';
```

Comment: copy and paste the select query displayed on the image in your question.

Comment: The view builder generates the query for you on the bottom. All the `JOIN` will be there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `appointmnent_id` is the primary key of `Appointment`, this table has a `1:N` relationship with all 6 tables.

This is the case where joining to these 6 tables will produce **multiple rows with duplicate data**, it's like a `Cartesian Product`. For example if (for only one `id=46`), there are:

- 3 rows for `PatientInvestigation`
- 6 rows for `PatientTreatmentMedicine`
- 4 rows for `PatientFindings`
- 2 rows for `PatientDiagnosis`
- 2 rows for `PatientCC`
- 5 rows for `PatientAdvice`

you'll get 3x6x4x2x2x5 = **`1440`** rows in the result set, while you only need 3+6+4+2+2+5 (+1) = **`23`** rows. That is 60 times more rows (and with many more columns) than needed.

It's better if you do **6 separate queries with one JOIN to one (of the 6) tables in each query** (and one more query to get the data from the base table `Appointment`). And **combine the results of the 6 queries in the application code**. Example for the base query and the query to join to the first table:

**Base table**:

```
SELECT 
    a.appointment_id, 
    a.patient_id
FROM 
    Appointment AS a
WHERE
    a.appointment_id = 46
```

**Join-1 to PatientInvestigation**:

```
SELECT 
    pi.investigation_name, 
    pi.investigation_id
FROM 
    Appointment AS a
      JOIN
    PatientInvestigation AS pi
        ON pi.appointment_id = a.appointment_id
WHERE
    a.appointment_id = 46
```

Comment: can i make a view for this approach?Then how will be it?

Comment: If you want View, you'd have to create 6(+1) views. Why do you need Views?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    Appointment.appointment_id, 
    Appointment.patient_id, 
    PatientInvestigaiton.investigation_name, 
    PatientInvestigaiton.investigation_id, 
    PatientTreatmentMedicine.medecine_id, 
    PatientTreatmentMedicine.medicinename, 
    PatientTreatmentMedicine.medicinetype, 
    PatientFindings.finding_id, 
    PatientFindings.finding_value, 
    PatientAdvice.advice_description, 
    PatientCC.cc_value, 
    PatientCC.cc_id, 
    PatientDiagonosis.diagonosis_name, 
    PatientDiagonosis.diagonosis_id
FROM 
    Appointment 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientInvestigaiton     ON Appointment.appointment_id = PatientInvestigaiton.appointment_id AND Appointment.appointment_id='46'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientTreatmentMedicine ON Appointment.appointment_id = PatientTreatmentMedicine.appointment_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientFindings          ON Appointment.appointment_id = PatientFindings.appointment_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientDiagonosis        ON Appointment.appointment_id = PatientDiagonosis.appointment_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientCC                ON Appointment.appointment_id = PatientCC.appointment_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PatientAdvice            ON Appointment.appointment_id = PatientAdvice.appointment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT {TABLE1}.appointment_id,{OTHER FIELDS} FROM {TABLE1}
    JOIN {TABLE2} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE2}.appointment_id
    JOIN {TABLE3} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE3}.appointment_id
    JOIN {TABLE4} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE4}.appointment_id
    JOIN {TABLE5} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE5}.appointment_id
    JOIN {TABLE6} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE6}.appointment_id
    JOIN {TABLE7} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE7}.appointment_id
    JOIN {TABLE8} ON {TABLE1}.appointment_id = {TABLE8}.appointment_id;
```

Try this:

```
SELECT
    dbo.Appointment.appointment_id, dbo.Appointment.patient_id,
    dbo.PatientInvestigaiton.investigation_name, dbo.PatientInvestigaiton.investigation_id, 
    dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.medecine_id, dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.medicinename, dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.medicinetype,
    dbo.PatientFindings.finding_id, dbo.PatientFindings.finding_value,
    dbo.PatientAdvice.advice_description,
    dbo.PatientCC.cc_value, dbo.PatientCC.cc_id,
    dbo.PatientDiagonosis.diagonosis_name, dbo.PatientDiagonosis.diagonosis_id
FROM
    dbo.Appointment 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientInvestigaiton
        ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientInvestigaiton.appointment_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine
        ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientTreatmentMedicine.appointment_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientFindings
        ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientFindings.appointment_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientDiagonosis
        ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientDiagonosis.appointment_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientCC
        ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientCC.appointment_id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.PatientAdvice
        ON dbo.Appointment.appointment_id = dbo.PatientAdvice.appointment_id
WHERE
    dbo.Appointment.appointment_id='46';
```

Comment: copy and paste the select query displayed on the image in your question, so i can modify it if needed.

Comment: Please take a look at the query i updated in the main post..i am getting multiple data after joining...is that ok?

Comment: OK..THAT WORKS FINE..NOW I HAVE THE VIEW...TELL ME HOW CAN I QUERY ON THIS VIEW TO GET DATA FOR A COLUMN..LIKE I WANT TO GET ALL THE MEDICINES FROM THE VIEW THAT IS FOR APPOINTMENT ID 46

Comment: He is selecting data from a table...i dont want that..tell me how to query on a view...you got me?