# When is better Multiple Queries instead of Multiple Joins?

Tags: sql, performance, select, join

There are a lot of similar questions of the type "Multiple Queries vs Single Query" in SO.
But I didn't see any with a general conclusion, therefore I'm still confused about this.

So, I will ask it in other terms:

**When is better to run Multiple Queries instead of a Single Query with Multiple Joins?**

I'm not asking for the trivial cases, obviously joining two, or 3 tables is much faster than executing 3 queries.

I'm thinking in cases for example where you have 10+ joins, and some of those joins are many to many relations, so your final query has GROUP_CONCAT, a mix of LEFT and INNER joins, etc.

For example, you want the *product* name, but also all their *images*, and also all their *tags*, and also all their *videos*, and also all the *directions* where you can buy it.
Is better to make a very long query with complex joins and group_concat (which is many times really difficult to manage if you can't use distinct), or executing a query for the product details, a query for the images, another one for the tags, etc. ?

I can write a particular example if it helps to clarify the question. But I was hoping a general rule for this situations.
**Where is the limit? when a single query with Joins is worst than multiple queries?**

and also, in those cases when is better to run multiple SELECT queries:
**is faster to run them inside a transaction (autocommit = false) ?**
**is faster to merge those multiple selects inside a single query with multiple subselects?**

Thanks !

Comment: Just an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771975/sql-joining-6-tables/6772599#6772599

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the limit? when a single query with Joins is worst than multiple queries?

I dont think it is easy to draw a limit, it depends a lot on your scenario and situations. There might be multiple factors like indexes, partitioning, joining columns, number of rows, structure of query e.t.c.

multiple joins, eg joining 5 columns, where joining columns are keys, values are not same for most of rows (eg gender) and  have proper indexes might be faster then the query which joins only two tables without proper indexes.

I guess One might set limits for oneself, eg you can decide that this particular use case (eg insert, or selecting) must not take more than 1 second, if it is taking more than that, more optimization might be required.

Comment: yes, but I was thinking in good queries, I mean with good indexes etc, using an index in a gender column is not good, and our joins should be done always using PK. At least that's what I do, all my tables has an ID, and I'm doing all my joins with that ID.

Comment: and what about the fastest way to run it?

Answer (score 1):

"It depends" is honestly the only valid answer. There is and can be no hard-and-fast "if greater than X joins then break it up" rule. (If there were, then X would have to change every few years. Stuff I write today would probably bog down the average server 10 years ago.)

With that said, the best tool for deteriming that cutoff point is experience. The more you write, test, and experiment with code, CROSS JOIN the more familiar you are with the hardware and data sets you have to work with "now", the better you will be able to write optimal queries. This is absolutely not to say that only gurus who sneer at the extensions of the SQL-92 standards can write optimmal queries. With reasonable effort new programmers can produce code that is "Good Enough" and, as the name says, that generally is good enough for most tasks.

Comment: You are right @Philip Kelley, but I was not expecting something so strict like a "more than X joins you need to split". I was expecting some type of guide, that is: (these are only examples I don't know if this is true) if you need group_concat, then maybe you should split, if you need more than group_concat with distinct then surely is better multiple queries, if you have situations like ... "X" then you probably is better multiple queries, etc. That is, when you choose multiple queries instead of multiple joins? and in that case is better to use autocommit false? is better to use subselects?

Comment: and what about the fastest way to run it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Where is the limit? when a single query with Joins is worst than multiple queries?
```

That would depend on the optimiser. As the query grows more complex, the risk of the optimiser selecting a poor execution plan increases.

Just selecting the order in which to process the tables can be done in N! ways, where N is the number of tables queried. With 5 tables there are 120 ways, with 10 tables a whopping 3628800. And that is just for one of the decisions that the optimiser must make.

Comment: so you are saying that the number of tables (joins) is a limit? for example if you have 10 joins then maybe is better to start to think in splitting it?

Comment: and what about the fastest way to run it?

Comment: I am saying that when you join many table there is a greater risk that the optimiser will make a poor choice. For Oracle I have observed this around 7+ tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you would join rather than run separate selects when you need the related data all at once OR if the related data is really big (e.g. LOBS with images...).

If you don't need the large related data all at once, then think "lazy initialization", where you query that large data when asked for.

Comment: and what about the fastest way to run it?

Answer (score 1):

I would also say, when the data transferred is orders of magnitudes larger than the individual queries.  Duplicated data per row can be a serious killer.

I had a query once, that individually, produced about 10megs of transferred data, but with the inner joins, produced 900 megs of data downloaded due to fields being repeated so many times.  The software spent 80% of its time just downloading the results of the query.  This is where software profiling comes into play, which will tell you where in your software you are spending the most time.